# Percentage margin differs in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, display

I am trying to adapt the hovering of my navigation bar, yet without success, my css so it will work for Chrome browser (only works fine in IE). The problem seems to be that the size of the display is not the same for both browsers and as I am using % values in the margin (to move tha navBar) they differ between IE and Chrome.

I have only found that I could include different stylesheets by previously checking (for example with javascript) the browser. However, I would like to find a solution css based. Any ideas?

The result I would like to have is to have underlined every section that it is been hovered and moved this line to the next section that will be hovered.

Here is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap');

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
 margin: 0px;
 background:black;
}
a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.container {
 /*margin-top:40px;*/
 width: 50%;
 background:black;
 margin-left:50%;
}
.white-line {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:-17px;
 width: 50%;
 background:white;
 height:1px;
 margin-left:50%;
 z-index:0;
}

ul li {
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight:500;
}

.navBar {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 padding: .50rem 0;
 margin: 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.one:hover ~ hr {
 margin-right: 75%;
 background: white;
 
}
.two:hover ~ hr {
 margin-right: 25%;
 background: white;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 25%;
 background: white;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 75%;
 background: white;
}

p{
 font-weight:300;
 font-size:25px;
 color:black;
}

hr {
 height: .25rem;
 width: 25%;
 margin: 0px;
 background: black;
 border: none;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  .container{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:20%;
 width:70%;

  }
  .white-line{
 margin-left:25%;
 width:70%;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
 
  .navBar{
 display:block;
   }
 
  .one:hover ~ hr , .two:hover ~ hr, .three:hover ~ hr, .four:hover ~ hr{
 background:transparent;
 width:20px;
  }

 .container{
 margin-left:25%;
  }

 .container ul li a:hover  {
 background:white;
 color: black;
 min-width:200px;
 margin-left:-80px;
  }
  .navBar {
 width: 200px;
    margin-left:-80px;
  }

  
 .white-line{
 background:transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title class="title">Welcome to NormMaster</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--Selected font Roboto-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>  
<!--navigatio bar-->
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a class="navBar" href="#">About</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a class="navBar" href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a class="navBar" onclick="openForm()" href="#">Register</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a class="navBar" href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>

<!--line-->
<div class="white-line">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance! :)

How it looks in IE11:
[image]

Comment: hello, on hover there should be problem. Right?

Comment: Can please give us clear picture what do want? so i can provide you a code.

Comment: It seems to me that if you want the white line to be touching the right margin, you should set `margin-right: 0` and not set margin-left. Other changes follow from that.

Comment: @RevtiShah yes, the problem is when hovering over each option in the navBar the line is not being placed right. In IE it appears underlying each section while in Chrome is not placed under the hovered section.

Comment: i fixed it in code. Please check it. I used (:after) psuedo class.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for your answer and capture! What I would like is to have the hover effect rightly placed in both browsers IE and Chrome. The navbar I want to keep it in the right top corner. If I change margin-rigth to 0 it is being moved to the left top corner.

Comment: @EpicaSjH Please dont use % for margins. otherwise it will create problem in all browser. Sometimes it okay with % but not everytime.

Comment: @RevtiShah thank you so much for your comments and advice! I checked your possible solution but ther I completely lose the effect of moving the line under the section that it's being hovered, and it is a thing I wanted to keep. I just wanted to fix that the line is not being correctly placed in Chrome browser.

Comment: @EpicaSjH Please check it. And let me know.

Comment: @RevtiShah Thanks again I checked your code and learn some things that I did know before! :). However the important element in my code that allows to create the effect of a line moving under the hovered sections is the <hr /> and that is why I believe it is gonna be difficult to have that effect from your approach without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the `<hr/>` tag's init position, if we use F12 developer tools to check the element, we can see that in the IE and Edge browser, the `<hr/>` tag locate in the middle of the white line. Screenshot as below:

[image]

But, in the Chrome and Firefox browser, the `<hr>` tag locates at the left of the white line. Screenshot like this:

[image]

To solve this issue, we could according to the browser to add the related CSS styles for the navigate bar, please refer to the following code:

```
    .navBar {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 24%;
        padding: .50rem 0;
        margin: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    /*Chrome browser*/
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
        .one:hover ~ hr {
            background: white;
        }

        .two:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 25%;
            background: white;
        }

        .three:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 50%;
            background: white;
        }

        .four:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 75%;
            background: white;
        }

        p {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: black;
        }
    }
    /*Microsft Edge browser*/
    @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
        .one:hover ~ hr {
            margin-right: 75%;
            background: white;
        }

        .two:hover ~ hr {
            margin-right: 25%;
            background: white;
        }

        .three:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 25%;
            background: white;
        }

        .four:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 75%;
            background: white;
        }
    }
    /*IE Browser*/
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

        .one:hover ~ hr {
            margin-right: 75%;
            background: white;
        }

        .two:hover ~ hr {
            margin-right: 25%;
            background: white;
        }

        .three:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 25%;
            background: white;
        }

        .four:hover ~ hr {
            margin-left: 75%;
            background: white;
        }
    }
```

Then, the result like this:

Chrome browser:

[image]

IE browser:

[image]

More details sample code, please check [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/amuLyfz7/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code. Hope it will work fine. If any changes please let me know.

https://jsfiddle.net/ysm2n58c/7/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap');

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
 margin: 0px;
 background:black;
}
a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.container {
 /*margin-top:40px;*/
 width: 50%;
 background:black;
 margin-left:50%;
}
.white-line {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:-17px;
 width: 50%;
 background:white;
 height:1px;
 margin-left:50%;
 z-index:0;
}

ul li {
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight:500;
}

.navBar {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 padding: .50rem 0;
 margin: 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.one:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 0;
 background: white;
 
}
.two:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 25%;
 background: white;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 50%;
 background: white;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
 margin-left: 75%;
 background: white;
}

p{
 font-weight:300;
 font-size:25px;
 color:black;
}

hr {
 height: .25rem;
 width: 25%;
 margin: 0px;
 background: black;
 border: none;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  .container{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:20%;
 width:70%;

  }
  .white-line{
 margin-left:25%;
 width:70%;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
 
  .navBar{
 display:block;
   }
 
  .one:hover ~ hr , .two:hover ~ hr, .three:hover ~ hr, .four:hover ~ hr{
 background:transparent;
 width:20px;
  }

 .container{
 margin-left:25%;
  }

 .container ul li a:hover  {
 background:white;
 color: black;
 min-width:200px;
 margin-left:-80px;
  }
  .navBar {
 width: 200px;
    margin-left:-80px;
  }

  
 .white-line{
 background:transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title class="title">Welcome to NormMaster</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--Selected font Roboto-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>  
<!--navigatio bar-->
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a class="navBar" href="#">About</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a class="navBar" href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a class="navBar" onclick="openForm()" href="#">Register</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a class="navBar" href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>

<!--line-->
<div class="white-line">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. However, what I wanted to keep is the hover effect but correctly placed. In this solution I completely lose the hover effect as theres no line "moving" over the section that it's being hovered. Thank you so much though! :)

Comment: Wait i will do with transition effect. Give me some time. I will do it.

Comment: Thanks again I checked your code and learn some things that I did know before! :). However the important element in my code that allows to create the effect of a line moving under the hovered sections is the <hr /> and that is why I believe it is gonna be difficult to have that effect from your approach without it.

Comment: @EpicaSjH Okay. I will try again. and let you know. it will work.

Comment: hey @EpicaSjH it works. I will share your code with update. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much again for your answer! It works fine for me in Chrome but not in IE. I was looking for something more related to what @Zhi Lv - MSFT posted as in that way I have the funcionality for both browsers. So, issue solved! :)

Comment: @EpicaSjH i have checked in IE11 . And it works well.Are you checking in Internet Edge?

Comment: Hey @EpicaSjH you can put hack code for particular browser then it will work.